# In google Sheets how to find the date of the highest stock price in 30-day period

Tags: google-sheets, stock

This formula returns the value of the highest price of the stock of a set period. How to modify it that it returns the date of the highest price, not the dollar value?

max(index(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","high",TODAY(),TODAY()-30,"DAILY"),0,2))

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a Frankenstein answer:

=TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "HIGH", TODAY(),TODAY()-60), 2, 0), 2,1))